# With C++17 is it possible to detect if a struct/class has any base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, type-traits

I need a type trait which will be true if the given type derives from anything, and false otherwise.

For example:

```
template<class T>
struct is_inherit
    //... logic of inheritance detection
    ;

template<class T>
void AppLogic(){
    if constexpr(is_inherit<T>::value) {
        puts("T has base");
        //...
    } else {
        puts("T doesn't have base");
        //...
    }
}

struct A {};
struct C {};
struct B: C {};

int main() {
    AppLogic<A>(); // print: T doesn't have base 
    AppLogic<B>(); // print: T has base
}
```

Is it possible to somehow implement that "is_inherit" trait struct?

---

Why?

I am developing a manual stack frame builder for Windows x64. According the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/return-values-cpp documentation, if a type:

- has a length of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits;
- has no user-defined constructor, destructor, or copy assignment operator;
- has no private or protected non-static data members;
- has no non-static data members of reference type;
- has no base classes;
- has no virtual functions;
- and has no data members that do not also meet these requirements;

then its return value is in the RAX register, otherwise the function
has a hidden argument that I must detect and handle.

This used to be the definition of a C++03 POD, however in C++11 this changed:

> Because the definition has changed in the C++11 standard, we do not recommend using `std::is_pod` for this test.

Up until now, with some conjugated traits I could detect if the type met the definition of a C++03 POD or not. However with C++17 the aggregate rules have changed, and that broke my solution.

If I can somehow detect whether a type T has any base class, my solution will work again.

Comment: If it has a base *in general*? Don't think you can do that without "cheating".

Comment: you need to wait for introspection to be added to C++, or find a compiler specific trick. I don't think you can do it otherwise. But as  Vittorio Romeo suggested, this could be a XY problem. Why do you need this? There could be a better way to solve your original problem.

Comment: Yep, in general, detect the given type has any base, dont like the std::is_base_of where i must give 2 types and the trait returns is the X inherits Y.

Comment: @Nyufu the question is what do you need this for? How would you use it? If we know the problem you are trying to solve we could maybe offer viable alternatives, which in fact could be better solution even if you could do what you are asking for. Or is this a philosophical question?

Comment: You can hack around this by having a `bool` that is set to `true` in the base and `false` in the derived classes. However, this does require you to do it manually. There are proposals to add reflection to C++, but I doubt it will be in C++17

Comment: Why is need this? Because of in my library I need to detect  is the given type is c++03 POD, and my solution has worked until C++ 17, where changed the aggregate rule, and the type can be aggregate even if has base class. And to make my is_cpp03 pod working again i need to detect the type has any kind of base class/struct.

Comment: There are a couple of things that come close, `std::is_trivial`, or `std::is_aggregate`. But what exactly is the problem are you trying to solve. No, not the one about figuring out whether a class has any base classes. But whatever problem to which you believe the solution involves determining whether a class has any base classes.

Comment: Isn't `std::is_pod` what you are after, really? Why should a base matter, so long as it's compatible with any C datatypes?

Comment: It's nice of them to specify that `std::is_pod` doesn't work, but it would be easier for everyone if they actually provided a solution which does :(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, at least for aggregates.

First we construct a class template that is convertible to any proper base of its template parameter:

```
template<class T>
struct any_base {
    operator T() = delete;
    template<class U, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<U, T>>> operator U();
};
```

Then we detect whether a template parameter `T` is aggregate constructible from a value of type `any_base<T>`:

```
template<class, class = void> struct has_any_base : std::false_type {};
template<class T>
struct has_any_base<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{any_base<T>{}})>> : std::true_type {};
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/g/pG5RXq).

Comment: if I had a class like `class E { E(B&) { }  };` I fear has_any_base_v would say true

Comment: @gu1d0 oh yeah, I forgot that `std::is_base_of` says that a class is its own base. Fixed to permit proper bases only. Thanks!

Comment: @gu1d0 yep, but if  the E has any constructor  then it isn't trivial therefore  isn't aggregate. ecatmur wrote this solution works "at least for aggregates".  This will be part of my C++03 POD detection trait, therefore this solution is sufficient for me.
`template<class T> struct is_cpp03_pod : std::bool_constant<std::is_trivial_v<T> && std::is_aggregate_v<T> && !has_any_base_v<T>> {};`

Comment: At least for aggregates... in which all of the subobjects after the first base class are default-constructible :)

Comment: @Nyufu How about `struct D { B b; };`?

Comment: @T.C. according the http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType "has no non-static members that are non-POD", so if the B is c++03 POD the D also will be POD. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/JMSBX6)

Comment: @Nyufu I'm talking about your own `B` in the question. What does your `is_c++03_pod` say for `D`? What should it say?

Comment: @T.C. Nice catch, and the answer is confusing me. Theoretically the D is non-POD. The B is non-POD because has base, and one of the D's member (b) non-POD therefore the D also. this is the theory. But according the msvc's [generated code](https://godbolt.org/g/Z5S4E9) in this case the D is POD because the main in the example code doesn't give the address of ret through RCX, but if you swap the func header,  the func expect the NRVO address in the RCX. That means according the msvc the D is POD and the B isn't. That's confusing. IDK, maybe something wrong in the msvc or in the documentation.

Comment: Uhh, I don't understand this. If it's a derived class then it's not an aggregate in the first place, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad Yes, you rigth. And i dont know, maybe i should write a mail for the microsoft to specify better the rules.

Comment: @Nyufu: It's weird that you accepted this answer if you also understand why it doesn't make sense... I'd have accepted the other one.

Comment: So, operator T() = delete is used to disallow conversion to itself. Neat.

Answer (score 9):

I believe that checking if "`T` derives from anything" is not possible, at least not in a standard-compliant way. If you are using this technique to check whether or not a type is a POD/trivial/aggregate, there are some type traits that might help you:

- [`std::is_pod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pod)
- [`std::is_trivial`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial)
- [`std::is_aggregate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_aggregate)

Comment: std::is_base_of